# How to validate terminal rule ID wtih Xtext IConcreteSyntaxValidator?

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, xtext

I would like to use Xtext's validation of the default terminal rule `ID` programmatically. Using the default example grammar:

```
Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;
    
Greeting:
    'Hello' name=ID '!';
```

and creating a `Greeting` entity with an invalid name (`ID` can't start with a number):

```
Greeting greeting = MyDSLFactory.eInstance.createGreeting();
greeting.setName("8Jane");
```

and checking it with the injected `IConcreteSyntaxValidator`:

```
IConcreteSyntaxValidator syntaxValidator = Activator.getInstance().getInjector("MyDSL")
    .getInstance(IConcreteSyntaxValidator.class);
ArrayList<Diagnostic> diagnostics = new ArrayList<Diagnostic>();
syntaxValidator.validateObject(greeting, 
    new IConcreteSyntaxValidator.DiagnosticListAcceptor(diagnostics), new HashMap<Object, Object>());
```

does not add an error message to `diagnostics`. Maybe it doesn't work because `ID` returns an `EString`? Or the IConcreteSyntaxValidator is not validating terminal rules? Is there another way?

EDIT: In the end I used the `DefaultTerminalConverters` to check if `text` is an ID:

```java
DefaultTerminalConverters valueConverter = Activator.getInstance()
                  .getInjector("MyDSL").getInstance(DefaultTerminalConverters.class);
try {
    valueConverter.ID().toString(text);
} catch (ValueConverterException e) {
  // give warning that text is not an ID
}
```

Comment: concretesyntax validator does not validate that. it is done by IValueConverter.

Comment: Thanks, it's working with injecting the `DefaultTerminalConverters` to get the `IDValueConverter`, is that the right way to access the converter?

Comment: see org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.tokens.ValueSerializer.serializeAssignedValue(EObject, RuleCall, Object, INode, Acceptor)

Comment: @Marie-Saphira Could you add code snippet, how did you used DefaultTerminalConverters to get it working.